# Microsoft Edge and window.resizeTo

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, window-resize

Please, consider the following:

`window.resizeTo(window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight)`

Ordinarily this should not visibly do anything as you're resizing the window to its original size.

However in Microsoft Edge there is some height and width that is not included in outerWidth/outerHeight and is added to the height/width provided in `resizeTo`

Has anyone seen this? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the zoom level of your browser.
Zoom does super weird things.